# DFA conversion through state elimination and arden's method

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I have tried to convert the following DFA to regular expressions through two different methods: Arden's method, and state elimination one. I have arrived to two different regular expressions: Arden's method: $0(10)^*$. State elimination method: $0(10)^*1$

Are these two regular expressions correct for this DFA?

This is the DFA:

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
| $\rightarrow$**A** : Start state | B |  |
| $\leftarrow$**B** : Final state |  | A |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first result $0(10)^*$ is correct. The second one is not, since the word $0$ should be accepted but dos not belong to $0(10)^*1$. You probably made a mistake when applying the state elimination method.

Comment: Can you show here how did you do state elimination please?

Comment: Sorry, but you should instead show what you have done in this regard.

Comment: It s Ok I corrected it. I had a problem when assigning the DFA's final state to the new GNFA's final state a phi, whereas I should have assigned an epsilon and the rest non final states a phi, I did it and I got the same RE as Arden's one.

Comment: Can you help with this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395409/anbn-language-vs-anbm